# How to format pre-formatted date from storage (not database) in Laravel

Tags: laravel, date, format

This question seems identical to other questions regarding dates but mine is quite unique. (Please respect).

In my AppServiceProvider inside Providers, I have this pre-formatted dates strings.

```
$dates = [
            '2018-04-23 11:02:01',
            '2018-04-03 09:52:14',
            '2018-03-27 06:42:33',
            '2018-03-15 08:59:14'
];

view::share('dates', $dates);
```

In my view, I have this;

```
<span>{{ $dates[1] }}</span>
```

...where the output is this;

> 2018-04-03 09:52:14

...when I am supposed to have an output like this:

> 04

...just the month. Is there any way I could satisfy the desired output?  Thanks!

Comment: How about ```Carbon\Carbon::parse($dates[1])->month```?

Comment: Yes, it works. Thank you @CUGreen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of options here.

First one is to use php with something like this:

```
date( 'm', strtotime($dates[1]))
```

Or, considering you are using Laravel, you could use Carbon:

```
Carbon\Carbon::parse($dates[1])->month
```

Comment: May I know why the use or what's the use of "Carbon/Carbon" per se? Thank you.

Comment: That is the full namespace for Carbon and is required in blade templates.

Comment: So since I have a pre-given strings, it's best to call it or use it in view, instead in the AppServiceProvider?

Comment: It's up to you where you use it, depends on your data requirements.